# I cannot fit my data logarithmically, How can I add log trendline?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

So this is my code, it's written a little messy and my result is absolutely ridiculous. I have no idea how to fix it.

[image]

Also, the seaborn library does not work on my computer in any way.
.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv('Data.csv',encoding="latin1",sep=";",engine="python")
table = data.replace(0, 0.1)
plt.plot(table["RMDM"], table["BSURF"], color="#03012d", marker=".", ls="None", markersize=3, label="")

data['RMDM'] = data['RMDM'].astype(float)

data['BSURF'] = data['BSURF'].astype(float)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x=data['BSURF']
y=data['RMDM']
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.style.use('classic')

plt.xlabel('B_LC')
plt.ylabel('RM/DM')
plt.plot(x,y, 'og')

from scipy.stats import linregress

df = data.loc[(data['RMDM'] >0) & (data['BSURF'] >0)]

stats = linregress(np.log10(df["RMDM"]),np.log10(df["BSURF"]))

m = stats.slope
b = stats.intercept
r = stats.rvalue

x = np.logspace(-1, 5, base=10)
y = (m*x+b)

plt.plot(x, y, c='orange', label="fit")
plt.legend()
#m,c=np.polyfit(x,y,1)
#plt.plot(x,m*x+c)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: ```y = (m*x+b)``` is not a line in a log linear plot. You need to also take the log of y.

Comment: Will you provide a link to the non-linear data.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

lmplot can be used to create a linear line through your data.  you correctly used np.log for the linear regression data.   keep x in terms of the log.

```
df['log_col1']=np.log(df['col1'])
sns.lmplot(x='log_col1','y='target', data=df, ci=None)
sns.scatterplot(y='target',x='log_col1',data=df)
plt.show()
```